# Multiple structural breaks with Chow test by incorporating dummies?

Tags: chow-test

I am trying to determine whether there are statistically significant structural breaks in a time series I am looking at. Graphically, I can see that there are two structural breaks, but I would need to do a formal test to confirm this.

What I have done so far is that I have estimated an OLS, which includes the constant and a t-1 lag to get rid of heteroskedasticity and autocorrelation otherwise present. I then do the Chow test for the first date of a break, and am successful in rejecting the null.

Would it be okay to then go back and re-estimate the model by including a dummy=1 for all periods after the first structural break, and then do a Chow test for the second suspected breakpoint?

Thank you in advance for any answers or ideas you may have on this. Also, if anyone has noticed any papers discussing this approach, that would be great.